# jQuery flot - fit time-axis tick labels without text overflowing for variable range chart

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I have a simple flot line chart with daily data samples. But the range is user selectable (anything from 2 days up to several years of data).

```
var chartConfig = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%Y/%m/%d"
    }
};

$.plot($("#chart"), readings, chartConfig);
```

I want the x-axis ticks to display dates (e.g. 2013/07/15), but for only a suitable number of ticks, evenly distributed across the range, to be shown so that the label text doesn't overflow (e.g. 10 ticks).

I've looked at **tickSize** and **minTickSize** but these are only 'guidelines' - above 4 ticks they have no impact in this use case.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I've written something myself to show a fixed number of ticks, regardless of data range.

It calculates the interval of which samples to show a tick for, and then uses the modulo operator to test whether to show the sample tick or not.

```
var ticks = [];
var tick_count = 7; //number of ticks to show
var sample_count = readings[0].data.length;
var display_interval = Math.round((sample_count/tick_count));
for (var i = 0; i < sample_count; i++) {
    if((i % display_interval) == 0) {
       ticks.push(readings[0].data[i][0]);
    }
}
chartConfig.xaxis.ticks = ticks;
$.plot($("#chart"), readings, chartConfig);
```

This assumes all the samples are of the same duration.